# Insert select query with custom values in node js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

I have a SQL query that looks like this.

```
var q = "INSERT INTO leave_taken_superior_map_dis_approved " +
    "(ltsm_id,ltsm_superior_id,ltsm_group_id,ltsm_all_approved,ltsm_overide_by_hr,ltsm_old_list,ltsm_leave_type,ltsm_message,ltsm_user,lstm_leave_reason) " +
    "SELECT ltsm_id,ltsm_superior_id,ltsm_group_id,ltsm_all_approved,ltsm_overide_by_hr,ltsm_old_list,ltsm_leave_type,ltsm_message,ltsm_user,lstm_leave_reason FROM leave_taken_superior_map WHERE ltsm_group_id = ?;" +
    "INSERT INTO affno_leave_taken_disapprove " +
    "(alt_id,alt_leave_date,alt_leave_text,alt_leave_taken_by,alt_leave_type,alt_other,alt_date_time,alt_group_by,alt_leave_applied,alt_leave_approved_by,alt_leave_approved,alt_superior_id) " +
    "SELECT alt_id,alt_leave_date,alt_leave_text,alt_leave_taken_by,alt_leave_type,alt_other,alt_date_time,alt_group_by,alt_leave_applied,alt_leave_approved_by,alt_leave_approved,alt_superior_id from affno_leave_taken WHERE alt_group_by = ?; " +
    "delete from leave_taken_superior_map where ltsm_group_id = ?;";
var qp = [groupID, groupID, groupID];
sqlq.executeQuery(q, qp).then((data) => {
    resolve(data)
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
    reject(err)
})
```

what I want here to do is to copy done data from a table and put it on another table and then delete that from the previous table. but there are some columns in the previous table that I need to change and add them to the new table. for ex. instead of the `ltsm_superior_id` from the leave_taken_superior_map, I want to add another value(let's say 5) to the new table(leave_taken_superior_map_dis_approved). is there any easy way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write the value you want, like this

```
INSERT INTO leave_taken_superior_map_dis_approved (ltsm_superior_id, ltsm_id,  ltsm_group_id, ltsm_all_approved, ltsm_overide_by_hr, ltsm_old_list, ltsm_leave_type, ltsm_message, ltsm_user, lstm_leave_reason)
  SELECT
    5, 
    ltsm_id,    
    ltsm_group_id,
    ltsm_all_approved,
    ltsm_overide_by_hr,
    ltsm_old_list,
    ltsm_leave_type,
    ltsm_message,
    ltsm_user,
    lstm_leave_reason
  FROM leave_taken_superior_map
  WHERE ltsm_group_id = ?;
```